# Recursive component does not load the child in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs, recursion, react-redux

I have the following component to display a set of comments (and their replies). If a comment has a non-empty `childPosts` array, then the component is again called with the ids of the childPosts. All comments are accessible from redux store through `props.discussionPosts`.

```
import * as React from 'react';
import { useState } from 'react';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';

const CommentItem = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.commentIds && props.discussionPosts &&
                props.commentIds.map(commentId => {
                    console.log(props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts)
                    var ident = 10;
                    return (
                        <div key={commentId} className="comment">
                            <div>{props.discussionPosts[commentId].content}</div>
                            {
                                props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts.length > 0  &&
                                <div style={{ marginLeft: '10px'}}>
                                    <CommentItem
                                        key={commentId} 
                                        commentIds={props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )    
}    

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    discussionPosts: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.discussionPosts,
    error: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.error,
    loading: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.loading
})


export default connect(mapStateToProps)(CommentItem);
```

I place this component in the main page with the following code, where the `commentIds` is set to the ids of the comments with no parent comment.

```
<CommentItem
      commentIds={props.discussionPosts.filter(function (x) {
                  return props.discussionPosts[x].parentPostId === null;
            })}
/>
```

However, the code only displays the top level comments with no parent comment:

```
Comment 1
Comment 2
```

What I want to achieve is this:

```
Comment 1
    Reply to c#1
Comment 2
    Reply to c#2
```

But, for some reason the following code inside the `CommentItem` component is not producing them:

```
 <CommentItem
        key={commentId} 
        commentIds={props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts}
 />
```

I am able to print the `childPosts` values correctly in the console. Below in the image you can see how the `discussionPosts` data looks like:

[image]

I am not receiving any error, but this recursive component does not work properly. Any help?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't have enough knowledge about redux but what if you create a component with `connect` and render it?

```
const CommentItem = (props) => {

    return (
        <div>
            {
                props.commentIds && props.discussionPosts &&
                props.commentIds.map(commentId => {
                    console.log(props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts)
                    var ident = 10;
                    return (
                        <div key={commentId} className="comment">
                            <div>{props.discussionPosts[commentId].content}</div>
                            {
                                props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts.length > 0  &&
                                <div style={{ marginLeft: '10px'}}>
                                    {// render connected component}
                                    <ConnectedCommentItem 
                                        key={commentId} 
                                        commentIds={props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts}
                                    />
                                </div>
                            }
                        </div>
                    )
                })
            }
        </div>
    )    
}    

const mapStateToProps = (state) => ({
    discussionPosts: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.discussionPosts,
    error: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.error,
    loading: state.alignPerspectivesReducer.loading
})

// create connected component
const ConnectedCommentItem = connect(mapStateToProps)(CommentItem);

export default ConnectedCommentItem;
```

Comment: Amazingly this worked.. But, I do not understand why this is necessary with Redux... Anyways, thanks!

Comment: It's not about redux, but any wrapper (HOC) you use. The first component will be rendered with `connect` but the component inside won't

Comment: Ah, that makes sense. Good catch, @Vencovsky. You could accomplish the same result by passing `discussionPosts` into `CommentItem` in the recursive call.

Comment: I think that it makes more sense to pass `discussionPosts` as @LukeMWillis mentioned.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like your `childPosts` might be an object rather than an array. If the data is structured like this:

```
childPosts: {
  0: 2
}
```

then `childPosts.length` will be undefined and your recursive element will never be rendered.

What you want is an array:

```
childPosts: [ 2 ]
```

then your code should work as written.

Answer (score -1):

Use `hasChildPosts` instead of `props.discussionPosts[commentId].childPosts.length > 0`